# Infinispan - How to know if a cache was defined in the config file (XML)?

Tags: infinispan

I'm using an embedded cache architecture in Infinispan that allows dynamically create/remove caches.

If an user tries to get a no existent cache, it needs to get an exception, but the `EmbeddedCacheManager` API is not helping on this. This API offers two options

- `get(String name, true)` - get and creates
- `get(String name, false)` get but not creates

My approach? when the user simple gets a cache we use `get(String name, false)`, and when  the user creates a cache we use `get(String name, true)`. So far, so good.

Now I have an issue: some of the caches are not created by the application, but defined in the XML. So, when a user gets one of these 'built-in' caches using `get(String name, false)` it do not get the cache.

We can solve these if we can identify the cache that were defined in the XML.

NOTE: For the moment, we are prefixing the name of the caches defined in the XML, but this is ugly for the code abstraction, and is getting very messy.

Comment: Hmmm, can't you load the XML, then call EmbeddedCacheManager.getCacheNames() and check whether the cache name is present in that set?

Comment: Do you mean read it not using the Infinispan API?

Comment: ?? I mean load the XML by calling the DefaultCacheManager constructor with it, then call getCacheNames()...